# What version of TWRP should I use with Android x?

Tags: recovery-mode, twrp

Reading the TWRP release notes I often read "TWRP is now basted on AOSP x.x" etc.

So, do I somehow need to match my TWRP and Android versions?
I guess TWRP will boot regardless of the Android version installed on my device, since that's the purpose of a recovery. But can it "understand" the specifics of a device running a certain Android version?
Like the change from `/data/media` to `/data/media/0` or device encryption?

So, it's probably not a good idea to use TWRP 1.x on a device running Android 11?
Also, is it a good idea to run TRWP 3.6.2 on a device running Android 6?
Is using the latest Version of TWRP always recommended?

I couldn't find an answer to this...